# What is the official rule on Albanian roundabouts?

Tags: legal, driving, safety, albania

When entering roundabouts in Albania we have witnessed **both** vehicles on the roundabout giving way to entering vehicles, and vehicles entering the roundabout giving way to vehicles on the roundabout.

In 90% of the European countries vehicles entering the roundabout give way.

Which way around is it, and what is the safest option when using them?

Comment: I haven't managed to find a definitive answer, but it will most likely be found in the [Albanian Traffic Code](https://qbz.gov.al/preview/ad1c89b1-88fa-402f-8456-a653dcbd44dd). However, my attempts to search it for terms such as _rrethrrotullimi_ (roundabout) have not yet borne fruit.
Another way to approach the question is to find out whether Albania follows the [Vienna Convention on Road Traffic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic) - I have found some links suggesting it does, but nothing strong enough to create an answer around yet.

Comment: @David I did drive through a roundabout or two in Kosovo, and it seemed clear there were no rules, other than `The Law of the Jungle.'

Comment: @MarkMayo I'm not sure what needs to be clarified – let me know and I'll update. The question is who yields to who, and what is the safest way to approach them assuming neither option are universally used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Albania is a signatory party of the [Vienna Convention on Road Traffic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic) and therefore should follow road rules similar to other European Countries. This includes yielding to vehicles coming from the right side they have priority (or left if driving in UK and other left-hand driving counties). Unless otherwise specified, this rule also applies in roundabouts: the vehicle coming into the roundabout has the right of way, except if clearly marked by the appropriate sign:

[image: give way sign]

Having said this, the is no guarantee that drivers respect this anywhere not just in Albania, and this is why accidents happen. The consensus on the internet seems to be that Albanian drivers have a tendency to dive in roundabouts regardless of priority. My advice is that your **drive carefully and defensively** and don't assume that having the right of way means that other drivers will yield. Do this everywhere, not just in Albania.